# Creating a vector results in memory leak in C

Tags: c, vector, valgrind

I am trying to create a vector in C, following is the struct declaration:

```
#define VECT_INITIAL_CAPACITY 4

typedef struct vect vect_t;

struct vect {
  char **data; // data is an array of strings             
  unsigned int size;      
  unsigned int capacity;   
};
```

I have a function that constructs a new empty vector, here is what I did:

```
vect_t *vect_new() {

  vect_t *v = (vect_t*) malloc(sizeof(vect_t));

  if (v == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  // Allocate memory for data
  v->data = (char**) malloc(VECT_INITIAL_CAPACITY * sizeof(char*));
  if (v->data == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < VECT_INITIAL_CAPACITY; i++) {
    v->data[i] = NULL;
  }

  // Initialize fields
  v->size = 0;
  v->capacity = VECT_INITIAL_CAPACITY;

  return v;
}
```

Valgrind tells me that the line `v->data = (char**) malloc(VECT_INITIAL_CAPACITY * sizeof(char*));` caused memory leak. But I'm not sure how to fix this. Can anyone point out what caused the memory leaks?

Edit: Added my cleanup code below:

```
/** Free all the memories of the vector. */
void vect_delete(vect_t *v) {

  // Delete data first
  for (int i = 0; i < v->size; i++) {
    free(v->data[i]);
  }
  // Delete the vector
  free(v);
}
```

Comment: You're not showing any cleanup code, so you'll need to post that.  Remember, anything that was returned from `malloc` should be passed to `free` to clean it up.

Comment: This code is very incomplete - for example what is `vect_t`

Comment: You have a delete function but do you actually call it?

Comment: If you **have to** cast the result of malloc then you compile the C code using C++ compiler and it is not right

Comment: PSA: If you're doing a lot of tricky allocations consider `calloc()` which makes it clear *what* and *how many* you're allocating in a very consistent way. Additionally, it's not necessary to [cast the result of an allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) in C.

Comment: `vect_t *vect_new()` in C++ it OK, in C not. `vect_t *vect_new(void)`

Comment: @tadman yes I called it in my tests.

Comment: show how do you call it

Comment: `v->data = malloc(...)` but there is no corresponding `free(v->data)`. Also: if the first malloc passes but the second fails you have a memory leak (it probably doesn't matter at that point, but still...)

Comment: Show how do you allocate memory for stings

Comment: `VECT_INITIAL_CAPACITY` "INITIAL" suggests you may `realloc()` at some time... Please understand that the `realloc()` in the "add to collection" function can cope (vey well) with an INITIAL allocation that is zero... Ponder on this...

Comment: @0___________ I added to my question

Comment: I noticed the allocation of memory for "v->data" based upon "VECT_INITIAL_CAPACITY", but in your cleanup function, you utilize element "v->size" in your for loop for freeing the data.  If that value is never changed from zero, I don't see the call to free ever happening.  Should you be using v->capacity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/** Delete the vector, freeing all memory it occupies. */
void vect_delete(vect_t *v) 
{
    if(v)
    {
        // Delete data first
        if(v -> data)
            for (size_t i = 0; i < v->capacity; i++)  //not v->size
            {
                free(v->data[i]);
            }
        free(v -> data);  //missing
        // Delete the vector
        free(v);
    }
}
```

Some remarks:

1. Use the correct type for sizes and indexes (`size_t`) not `int` or `unsigned`
2. Use objects instead of types in `sizeof`s. `vect_t *v = malloc(sizeof(*v));`
3. Do not cast the results of `void *` functions like `malloc`.  If the code does not compile, then you use the wrong compiler (C++ one) to compile C code.

Comment: BTW, good use of `if(v)`.  Simplifies calling calling code' responsibilities.

Comment: May I ask the purpose of having free(v->data) after the for loop?

Comment: @d0nut because you allocate memory for it

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@0___________](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75368728/2410359) good answer,

`if (v->data == NULL) { return NULL; }` also leaks.

Use `if (v->data == NULL) { free(v); return NULL; }`.